# How do I offer the choice to run the program again or end it in Python?

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

I'm trying to run this program which takes a message from the user and then prints it out backwards. The while loop works but at the end I'd like to implement a decision point that carries on or exits altogether.

See here:

```
print("\nHi, welcome to my program that will reverse your message")

start = None
while start != " ":
    var_string = input("\nSo tell me, what would you like said backwards:")
    print("So your message in reverse is:", var_string[::-1])


input("Press any key to exit")
```

Please advise how I may include something like  'input("\nIf you want another go, tell me what:)' which would restart the loop if the user decides to. Would this be an if/or indentation?

This is early days for me.

Comment: Read about how ``while`` works. You already have an answer in your question.

Comment: what have you tried? maybe this is something you could do yourself easy!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has less to do with `while` loops, and more with conditional statements and `continue` / `break` statements, i.e. "control flow tools". See my suggestions in the edit to your code below:

```
print("\nHi, welcome to my program that will reverse your message")

# This bit is unnecessary. Why use the `start` variable if you're never going to 
# reassign it later in your program?
#start = None 
#while start != " ":

# Instead, use `while True`. This will create the infinite loop which you can
# 'continue` or `break` out of later.
while True:
    var_string = input("\nSo tell me, what would you like said backwards:")
    print("So your message in reverse is:", var_string[::-1])

    # Prompt the user again and assign their response to another 
    # variable (here: `cont`).
    cont = input("\nWould you like another try?")

    # Using conditional statements, check if the user answers "yes". If they do, then
    # use the `continue` keyword to leave the conditional block and go another
    # round in the while loop.
    if cont == "Yes":
      continue

    # Otherwise, if the user answers anything else, then use the `break` keyword to 
    # leave the loop from which this is called, i.e. your while loop.
    else:
      input("Press any key to exit")
      break
```